# limit to infinity and uniformly convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f_n(x)$ and $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f (x)$.

$f_n, f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (Here $f_n$ is uniformly converge to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ )

Then, Does the statement "$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)  = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}  f_n(x)$ (I.e $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{n  \to 
\infty}\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}  f_n(x)$  )" hold?

Most of the problems I've ever seen the limit to finite real value not the infinity, So I can't figure out it hold.  But just my guess, though it looks like a true. If it is correct, how could I prove it? (Are there any counter example of that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon,~~~~x\in\mathbb{R},~~~~n\geq N,
\end{align*}
taking $x\rightarrow\infty$ we get
\begin{align*}
|\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)|\leq\epsilon,~~~~n\geq N,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}(x)\rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x),~~~~n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align*}